# unable to mount pendrives etc

Tags: users

All of a sudden in 11.10 I am no longer even though administrator able to mount New volumes such as pen drives. etc. Also my User Account unlock is now greyed out.
If I log in as a guest I can mount volumes but not as administrator.
Everything else such as root etc seems ok its probably to do with the grayed in unlock on the user account. Ideas please.

Update: If I hover mouse over padlock even though I am logged in its says 
System policy prevents changes  Contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/851055), it seems like the only workaround is to remove LightDM and install GDM over it.

Can you try the following commands?

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Comment: Yes this looks like its working Thank you.Its a bit longer logging in but.. Now I can copy all of my home folder to a dvd or pendrive and just upgrade to 12.04 where hopefully it will not repeat itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link: http://www.ubuntux.org/how-to-change-the-root-password-in-ubuntu, or this one: http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/04/23/how-to-login-as-root-in-ubuntu-11-04/, or this video which shows how to do it from Grub: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9j8Pm6QWiHg

Comment: Sun Dial  the problem is not using the password its that for some reason I am locked out as administrator from mounting new volumes and the padlock symbol in users is greyed out (this is why i presume its happening) thanks